# Media Queries only partially working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been designing UI for a little while now but this is my first time using Media Queries. I'm trying to use:

```
<style media="screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1280px)">
    #signature li a {height:35px}
</style>
```

With the HTML looking like this:

```
 <span id="signature" style="display: block;"><li ><a href="signedreports.jsp?p=signature">Manage Names</a></li></span>
```

I'm trying to have the style within the media query hold true whenever the code is on a 1280 X 1024 screen. When I load the page on a 1280 X 1024 screen it does work but when I click on the  link on the page the style goes away.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the Media Query? Do you know what I can do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need `(min-width: 0px)`

Comment: Sounds to me like you are clicking on the link, going to a different page that doesn't have your inline style?  Also, your HTML is semantically incorrect.  The only HTML element that can be a child of a UL/OL is an LI, you should move your <span> to be inside the LI, rather than wrapping it.

Comment: Are you going to a different page when you click on the anchor? Do you have other styles for the anchor? because if not then that height 35px does not do anything since anchor tags are display inline

Comment: It's still doing it. It's weird because I can click any other link on the page and it holds true. It just disregards the style change when I click on the link itself that the media style is on.

Comment: @AprilRandolph can you try to answer the questions asked in the comments above? or create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's a large application with multiple layers of tags and the tag that this is on is not changing. The link updates another part of the table on the screen so the url is changing with the response but the tag is not the part of the page being reloaded.

Comment: @AprilRandolph Have you tried to inspect the anchor tag after you clicked and see if the media query is still on it? Can you use @ name to reply so I know you have replied

Comment: @Huangism http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph01/KtejX/ Here is a jsfiddle of what it is like but this is a bad example because the media doesn't seeem to be changing the height of the Span so the height still looks like 17px and then when you click on the link the link is no longer showing. But I thought I would post it anyway so maybe someone would edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you putting this as an inline style and not in a css sheet?

Try this inside your css file;

```
@media all and (max-width: 1280px) {
#signature li a {height:35px}
}
```

Comment: `@media all and (max-width: 1280)` missing px and also `1280 X 1024` is width x height

Comment: You are targeting width between 1024px and 1280px when the OP is trying to target 0px to 1280px

Comment: My mistake, i miss read the original post when i seen 1280 x 1024. I have edited my post slightly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question then here is one of the solutions  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qtDsb)

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="signedreports.jsp?p=signature">Manage Names</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>




 li {
      list-style:none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      li {font-size:30px; color: green;}
       }
```

Comment: I don't even know how this is related to the question